# Best way to implement Failover Pattern for Java Clients

Tags: java, client, design-patterns, failover

We are designing a Java client (will be deployed on Tomcat, Windows 2008 R2) which needs to subscriber for some JMS topics on Sonic MQ.

Client wants to have to redundancy for this Java client and at any point of time, only one subscriber should be subscribed for topics.

Our requirement is similar to the this [post](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t132288-failover-pattern.html).

Is there's any standardized open source project which is built for this purpose or we have to write our own code to check the server health (time-consuming)? 
What's the best way to implement this Java Client.

We are exploring the below technologies for consuming JMS messages:

- Spring Integration
- Apache Camel

Are we going in the right direction? We should be able to start/stop the subscriptions to the topics on fly.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Camel have something like this out of the box check [this](http://camel.apache.org/load-balancer.html). It implements EAI Load Balancer pattern. You can choose "Failover" Policy. seems to be using Exception to decide which processor to go next.

Other way to do can be to implement simple custom jms based hearbeats among subscribers to keep track of each other health and balance load or failover. Each Subscriber can keep track of what they are suppose to process. For example from the link you provided each subscriber knows the subject it is listening to and keep receiving hearbeat from other subscriber in case of heartbeat failure failover listener will start taking messages for failed listener. I think you can use JMS Message Selector to implement filters. A good reference to start with can be [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2002/jw-0315-heart.html)  old article on Javaworld.